# Problems setting related reference while uploading attachments to Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, http, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm having some problems sending my attachment. It looks like this:

```
{
    "filename": "Test.txt",
    "subject": "Test",
    "mimetype": "text/plain",
    "documentbody": "SABlAGwAbABvACAAVwBvAHIAbABkAA==",
    "objectid@odata.bind": "/accounts(3ba2f6ab-3849-e811-a83b-000d3a2b2acb)",
    "isdocument": true
}
```

The error I get:

```
"error": {
    "code": "0x0",
    "message": "An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An undeclared property 'objectid' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value was found in the payload. In OData, only declared navigation properties and declared named streams can be represented as properties without values."
```

This as per documentation found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/create-entity-web-api#associate-entity-records-on-create

Any clue what is wrong here? Am I defining the relation between the annotation and account wrong?

Comment: I recommend you to use CRM REST builder to build such requests, I prefer it over postman for CRM metadata support & testing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works without any issue. `objectid_account@odata.bind` is absolutely necessary because `objectid` can store any entity. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/annotation?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9#single-valued-navigation-properties)

```
var entity = {};
entity.subject = "arun test";
entity["objectid_account@odata.bind"] = "/accounts(4B91608D-3C5A-EA11-A811-000D3A5A1CAC)";
entity.notetext = "blah blah";
entity.filename = "arun.txt";
entity.documentbody = "SABlAGwAbABvACAAVwBvAHIAbABkAA==";
entity.isdocument = true;

Xrm.WebApi.online.createRecord("annotation", entity).then(
    function success(result) {
        var newEntityId = result.id;
    },
    function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);
```

Comment: One thing to note here is the (s) on accounts. It's baffling why you have to use the plural table name. After noticing that detail it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try below, you are missing MimeType, which is important to know what type of attachment is. Just tried on one of my system and it works.

```
{
    "filename": "Test.txt",
    "documentbody": "SABlAGwAbABvACAAVwBvAHIAbABkAA==",
    "objectid@odata.bind": "/accounts(3ba2f6ab-3849-e811-a83b-000d3a2b2acb)",
    "isdocument": true
    "mimetype": "text/plain";
    "subject": "testing from CRM Webapi 33";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @AnkUser ! I've tried adding both mimetype and subject with no luck.

Comment: I believe you are using Webapi? Did you got same error as above? Strange!! it worked for me. I edited my answer, there was formatting error, but did you just extended your . Hope you are using Post metod with url as `/api/data/v9.1/annotations`

Comment: I'm using v8.2, it WORKS if i specify "objectid_account@odata.bind"

Comment: I tried to set 9.1 and back to objectid@odata.bind - that does not work